# Help with directional derivative to the direction of the tangent of a curve.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative, vector-analysis

i'm kinda stuck in a problem of the book Advanced Calculus of Watson Fulks. The problem is:

Calculate the directional derivative of $x^2+y^2-3xy$ on the point $P=(1,2)$ that goes to the tangent direction to the curve $y=x^3$.

Well, my problem is that i don't really get the idea of the tangent direction to a curve, i parametrize $y=x^3$ into $r(t) = (t, t^3)$ and then i derivate $r$ and that gives me $r'(t) = (1, 3t^2)$, but then i don't really know what to do.

Comment: Are you sure its $P=(1,2)$ ?. The curve doesnt pass through it.

Comment: Yeah, i'm sure of that, and that's also the problem

Comment: Well if the curve pass through the point, say $(1,1)$ then $x=t=1$. So you can find the velocity vector at that point as $r'(1)= (1,3(1)^2) = (1,3)$. And then you can apply the formula to calculate the dir. derivative.